# Doctrine Entity listener in symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Iam a little confused while I try to set up a doctrine entity listener with injected parameters in symfony.

First there is this page where Entity Listeners are barely mentioned:

> https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html
>
> In Doctrine 2.4, a feature called Entity Listeners was introduced. It
>   is a lifecycle listener class used for an entity. You can read about
>   it in the Doctrine Documentation.

Then here is explained, that I only have to add a service with the right tags and that I don't have to register the listener in the entity when using doctrine 2.5 (which I do):

> https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineBundle/entity-listeners.html
>
> If you use a version of doctrine/orm < 2.5 you have to register the
>   entity listener in your entity as well:

But the latter is not mentioned on the doctrine page:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners

However, following the doctrine page, I also added to my entity yaml:

```
AppBundle\Entity\File:
    type: entity
    entityListeners:
        AppBundle\EventListener\FileListener:
            postRemove: [postRemove]
```

And that is my Listener Class (still for testing):

```
class FileListener {

    public function postRemove(File $file) {

        dump($file); die();           
    }
}
```

That is what I set up in the service.yml:

```
file_listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\FileListener
        arguments: ['%path_image%', '%path_thumb%', '%path_preview%']
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener }
            - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener, entity_manager: custom }
```

But when deleting a File Entity, the Listener Method is not called.

Comment: [Listening on an entity with an entity listener](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/faep/listening-on-an-entity-with-an-entity-listener). This is the official documentation: [Entity listeners class](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners-class)

Comment: thats what I linked  too. But I just found the solution: its simply working though, but only when I remove the entity directly. Before I always removed the inversed side of a `oneToMany` and the File entity was removed by a delete cascade. It looks like the event is unfortunately not fired in that case.

Comment: Are you using `onDelete="CASCADE"` by any chance?

Comment: yes, thats what I just said, didnt I?

Comment: 1. Don't be arrogont. 2. Read up on why you shouldn't use `onDelete="CASCADE"` for such cases.

Comment: oh sorry, that was not intended to sound arrogant. Its just that I did not understand why you ask this again. But I understand now, that there are different approaches to cascade a deletion (cascade: [remove] instead of ondelete: cascade)